# Como passar argumentos de linha de comando em PHP?

Tags: php

Galera eu gostaria de fazer aqueles scripts que passam argumentos.

Ex. `php script.php -email JhonDoe@gmail.com`

Onde posso encontrar documentaçoes sobre isso?

PS: só quero saber como passar estes argumentos

Answer (score 6):

Use `$argv`, assim:

```
var_dump($argv);
```

É semelhante ao [c](/questions/tagged/c)

Note que `$argv[0]` sempre retorna o nome do script chamado, por exemplo no Windows:

```
C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop>php teste.php foo bar
Array
(
    [0] => C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\teste.php
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
)
```

Para remover o primeiro item pode usar `array_shift`, assim:

```
<?php

$argumentos = $argv;
$script = array_shift($argumentos);

echo $script, '<br>';

echo 'Argumentos:<br>';

var_dump($argumentos);
```

Supondo que queira pegar elementos específicos nem precisará do `array_shift`, se sabe que deseja pegar o primeiro parâmetro e o segundo por exemplo, basta checar com uma IF() a quantidade (use o `$argc` para obter a quantidade de parâmetros passados) e então **pegar pelo índice especifico**:

```
if ($argc >= 3) {
    $primeiro = $argv[1];
    $segundo = $argv[2];
} else {
    die('Parâmetros incorretos');
}
```

Documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: cara se eu precisar fazer perguntas tipo. Qual seu nome ? e esperar uma resposta?

Comment: @LucasBicalleto uma pergunta seria um input que espera o usuário digitar?

Comment: Isso, como posso fazer isso e recupera os dados? desculpe abusar das perguntas :/

Comment: Posta como uma nova pergunta por favor, assim que o fizer eu já posto uma nova resposta lá.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [$argv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php) que [são variáveis pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.php):

```
<?php

    var_dump($argv);
```

**Linha de comando:**

```
php args.php -email stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com
```

**Saída:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "args.php"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "-email"
  [2]=>
  string(31) "stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com"
}
```

<sub>A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php) está no site [php.net](http://php.net).</sub>

---

Se por acaso quiser contar a quantidade de argumentos utilize [$argc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argc.php), que também faz parte das [variáveis pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.php):

**Linha de comando:**

```
php args.php -email stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com
```

**Saída:**

```
int(3)
```

**Observações:** *tanto* [$argv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php) *e* [$argc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.php) *precisam que [register_argc_argv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) esteja habilitada para funcionar e o que define um argumento do outro é o espaço*.

***Referencias:***

- [$argv - Array de argumentos passados para o script](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php)
- [PHP args - How to read command line arguments in PHP](http://alvinalexander.com/php/php-read-command-line-arguments-in-php)
- [variáveis pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.php)
- [register_argc_argv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv)